# Warframe Squad Connection Issues

Tags: technical-issues, warframe

So me and my buddy are having issues connecting with each other to do missions in a squad, and I was wondering if someone could help.

Every time I invite him into a squad, it shows him on my screen, but on his it doesn't. And when I start the timer, the game displays that he disconnects when it gets down to 3 seconds.

When he invites me, the character icons at the top left disappear and I don't load into his game or his squad.

Any assistance is welcomed!

Comment: Sounds like a firewall/port issue. Are there specific ports that need to be opened on your router/firewall in order for the connection to succeed?

Comment: See [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/247122/106901) if you need step by step instructions on how to port forward

Comment: @Aequitas Page Not Found :(

Comment: @Ms.Nobody i've undeleted my answer to this question which is essnetially the same as that other answer I mentioned. Hopefully it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have similar issues with connecting to games others were in, even if they were in my squad before the mission.

I solved this by changing certain settings.  To get to these settings, start running warframe so that you get the page that checks for updates.  Instead of clicking "Play," go to the gear/settings icon in the corner.  Try playing with what versions of DirectX you are using.  That fixed it for me.

Comment: Fixing the directx oddly enough solved the issue

Comment: @LucidiousXIV I know, it's not something you would expect to cause problems, but for some reason it causes connection issues.  Your game might not be as pretty, but at least you can play with your friends.

Answer (score 1):

The first test is with each own's connection. See if both of you have a stable connection for general purposes (using social media, watching videos, downloading large files, like games...).

If you are safe about those, open Warframe, set your game mode to **public** and go to a popular node (**alerts**, **boss nodes**, **infestation nodes**, **invasion nodes**...) and see if each of you can connect to other people and have a stable connection with them. If you played the entire match with no Host Migration resulting in any of you getting back into the Landing Craft or in a Solo mission, you should have **no big connection problems**.

In my case, I have a pretty good connection in terms of bandwidth, downloading in a decent speed and using any website with ease, but I could only play Warframe games **as a host**, because if I entered as a client I would surely disconnect in the middle of the game.

Since Warframe **uses the host's connection** as a support to the game lobby, either you enter your friends game (and it works, because the settings may be different) or either of you should have your router checked for correct port forwarding and connectivity.

Hope I helped you troubleshoot, happy gaming!